# Change request Content-Type to allow invalid/unsupported request Content-Types

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

A client is currently sending our ASP.NET 4.x/Core REST APIs the correct request payload but invalid request `Content-Type` which is resulting in 415 status codes being returned. Obviously the client sending the invalid `Content-Type` is an issue but I'd like to consider a server side fix as an interim solution.

One solution which seems to resolve the issue is to modify the request `Content-Type` in the middleware as an example shown below:

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
{
    if (context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] == "invalid json header")
    {
        context.Request.Headers["Content-Type"] = "application/json";
    }
}
```

However I'm wondering if there's a better/more elegant solution that doesn't involve adding extra middleware?

Edit: another potential solution is to add `application/octet-stream` to `JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes` which is what the `Content-Type` defaults to in cases where its omitted/invalid but I think this will force `application/octet-stream` requests to read as `application/json` requests which isn't ideal either as we do get media upload requests with `application/octet-stream` as `Content-Type`

```
config.Formatters.JsonFormatter.SupportedMediaTypes.Add(new MediaTypeHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
```

Comment: Ask client to change that it's the best solution.

Comment: Like I said, this would be ideal but client can't fix it in a realistic time frame so to avoid disruption to the client I'm looking to fix on server side at least in the interim where ideally we would change or re-mapp the invalid request content-type to the correct content-type

Comment: Do you need to do this for just one enpoint or for all of them?

Comment: Multiple/all endpoints

Comment: This is not a fix in my option. Fix is what you do for a bug in you code and this is not a bug. You can change it where ever you can alter the http request. But in my opinion do it the last stage in the pipeline where ever it is possible.

Comment: If we talk about checking the `Content-Type` and setting the correct Content-Type for the invalid content Type then it will also accept the actual invalid requests and your code will change its content type to a valid one. It will be a loophole and create more issues in your Web API. So I would suggest you request your client to fix on their end even for the interim period.